# ROOT LogIn Times out / Error

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh

I'm looking at my friends server(dedi)

Server is ON no problems on host, when we contacted them, they said it is on our End. He has only XtreamCodes installed on it (paid) and it works just on panel keeps going off and on every now and then.

When I/he tries to log in via SSH sometimes it goes through with a massive lag or time out and other times it does not log in at all just times out and throws in an Error, mind you server is on and working.

What could be the culprit to tihs and how could we fix this, without Re-Installing and losing all Data.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you output faulty ssh command and error messages? Is it not connectivity issue? Which of them is Ubuntu? Server or client?

Comment: HI @Redbob It's the server while i'm using PuTTy it does not want to connect to SSH at all and when it does it Laaaaags, takes a while to respond for each command.